# Which is the best video player for HD, BrRip,BdRip,H.264?

Tags: windows-xp, video, media-player

I am looking a video player hopefully one that works with Windows XP and only for HD, BrRip, BdRip, H.264 quality movies. I am using CyberLink but not really happy with that.
Tried VLC but the picture quality is very poor. WM11 is good only for audio. 
So help me with this.Thanking you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using [Media Player Classic Home Cinema](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/) for some time.

You may also want to look at alternate codecs for your content:

[ffdshow tryouts](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/) is free

[CoreAVC](http://corecodec.com/products/coreavc) is $13 (worth every cent IMHO)

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out [SMPlayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/) Not sure if the picture quality will be better than VLC for sure though. I haven't invested in HD yet.

Answer (score 0):

Give **[GOM Player](http://www.gomlab.com/eng/GMP_download.html)** a shot together with [CCCP (Combined Community Codec Pack)](http://www.cccp-project.net/).

Comment: Thankyou, but i already tried GOM player...not satisfied with that.